# Use of sleep() in threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am new to the whole concept of threads and their execution. I've been working on a program to further understand how they work.

Here's the code that I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int glob;
void *child(void *t);
pthread_t thread[10];


void *child(void *t)
{
    // Increment glob by 1, wait for 1 second, then increment by 1 again.
    printf("Child %d entering. Glob is currently %d\n", t, glob);
    glob++;
    sleep(1);
    glob++;

    printf("Child %d exiting. Glob is currently %d\n", t, glob);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    glob=0;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, child, (void *) i ) ;
    }
    printf("Final value of glob is %d\n", glob);
    return 0;
}
```

While I understand that their execution times are unpredictable. And therefore, the printing and updating of glob will be messed up. But why doesn't the latter part of the threads, after the sleep(1) execute at all?

Any help is appreciated.

My current output:

```
Child 0 entering. Glob is currently 0
Child 3 entering. Glob is currently 0
Child 2 entering. Glob is currently 0
Child 1 entering. Glob is currently 0
Child 4 entering. Glob is currently 3
Child 5 entering. Glob is currently 5
Child 6 entering. Glob is currently 6
Child 7 entering. Glob is currently 7
Child 8 entering. Glob is currently 8
Final value of glob is 9
Child 9 entering. Glob is currently 9
```

Comment: Show us *exactly* what output you are getting.

Comment: From the [`sleep` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html): "**`sleep()`** may be implemented using **`SIGALRM`**". You can only have one "alarm" active per *process* (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Printf is not thread safe. Also, you've got multiple threads performing a non-atomic operation on a global without a mutex.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That text is outdated. POSIX requires `sleep` to be thread-safe. See [Austin Group bug #625](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=625).

Answer (score 3):

Since your main thread doesn't wait for the threads, it's likely that main threads exits *before* the threads could print the parts after `sleep()`. Hence, exiting the whole process.

Call `pthread_join()` from main for all threads and you'll see the printf's after sleep() call being printed. As you are already aware, there's a *race condition* when updating the `glob` by all threads. So you can't make much sense out of this program.

Comment: Or use `pthread_exit` to exit from `main` instead of `return`. But obviously this will not help for your race condition, either.